# How to create a downloadable URL for a zip file in Django?

Tags: python, django, url

I am trying to create a webpage that has a table where one of the columns in that table downloads a particular file that resides in my computer. The file that is supposed to be download is based on the ID number of that row.(ID is a column in my table)

Ex. If the user clicks on the URL that is in the 3rd row then the file named '3.zip' in my local files should get downloaded.

I have tried the `<a href="<path>" download>` in my HTML template file but I realized in Django the method is different. Then I used the HTTPResponse as an attachment method.

This is my Views.py code for download.

```
def download_file(request):
    fl_path = '/home/harish/Desktop/cvision/users_output_files/5/5.zip'
    filename = '5.zip'

    with open(fl_path, 'r') as zip_file:
        response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/force-download')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"'%filename
        return response
```

## Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.homepage),
    path('add',views.datapage),
    path('newdata',views.newdata),
    path('newuser',views.newuser),
    path('download_file/',views.download_file)
]
```

So, When I go to path `http://127.0.0.1:8000/download_file` the file is supposed to get downloaded. But instead I get an error.

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

If we ignore the Encoding error how can I solve the problem of downloading a particular file from local folders based on the ID of that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have an idea it is better save your file in static or media folder and add media/static url root setting to your urls.py file

setting.py

```
 # Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and finally you can serve you file in django template with link like as

```
<a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/files/somefile"> download</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/files/somefile"> download</a>
```

Comment: But how do I deal with the ID number problem? This method is not fetching the ID value so that I can specify my path to a pirtucular .zip file?

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I deal with the ID number problem? This method is not
>   fetching the ID value so that I can specify my path to a pirtucular
>   .zip file?

probably you want to create a table like as blow

```
 {% for student in student_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.student_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.user.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.user.last_name }}</td>
            <td align="center"><a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/files/{{ forloop.counter }}.zip"></a>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

{{forloop.counter}} is your id number

Comment: <a href="/home/harish/Desktop/cvision/media/{{data.id}}.zip" download> this is the href I gave. but is says unable to open '/{{data.id}}.zip' . What is MEDIA_URL btw? Have I used it correctly?

Comment: please read this article
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: What is MEDIA_URL btw?
in first answer i say you how to use it.
media and static, they are  folder for your static files like img, css, js and etc.
these folders are in your project directory,